# Play 2.1: Logger doesn't work

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, playframework-2.1

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/test%2420log/play-framework/ydU081RerA8/LWDDUj6rJDwJ) and [the source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L244), logger in Play 2.0 is disabled in test mode. In Play 2.1.x, the if condition seems to have been removed (see [source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Logger.scala#L245)), so I guess logger can be used in test mode in Play 2.1, but it's not the case for me.

I use `play.api.Logger` (I program in Scala) and the default configuration. Here is how I use it:

In `app/controllers/Application`:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Logger

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Logger.error("Here's index!")
    Ok(views.html.index("Hello"))
  }
}
```

In `conf/routes`:

```
# Home page
GET         /                               controllers.Application.index
```

Comment: Please show some code (config, usage...).

Comment: @nico_ekito I've added the usage as you said (config is all default), thanks :)

Comment: And how are you testing this controller ?

Comment: I ran 'play' in the command line and go to http://localhost:9000 and expect to see the logging "Here's index" in the terminal.

Comment: When you run `play` in your command line, you'll have then to type `run` in order to connect to your server. And I think you should get un error, since the code of your controller does not compile (it should return a `Result`, not a `Any` returned by `Logger.error`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Sorry I forgot to paste the `Ok(...)` line and I was meant to say "run `play run`". My code compiled and I can see "Hello" in `http://localhost:9000`, but I still can't get the logging working.

Comment: I just tested with Play 2.1.1, it works correctly. Strange :(

Comment: You used the default configuration for logging? It's strange indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing duplicated SLF4J and log4j libraries in the classpath, thanks @nico_ekito for his helps!

Comment: great to see that you solve the issue, I was wondering what was happening :-)